# UIViewController isn't deinitialized

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    // ...

    deinit {
        print("test deinit")
    }

    // ...

    func exit() {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    // ...
}
```

This is (the part of) my view controller that always pushed in navigation controller when it present.

And I want it deinitialized when it popped out of navigation controller.

But It was never printed "test deinit" when it popped out by anything methods(call `exit()`, swipe ... etc).

And I guess the presenting method could make this issue. So I was test to presenting with below two methods. but I couldn't resolve it in any way.

```
let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard").instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as! MyViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

or

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToMyVC", sender: nil)
```

What's the problem? How do I deinitialize it?

Comment: check your closures, and delegates must be something wrong and your viewController is being retained

Comment: @ReinierMelian Thanks. That's right. I wasn't put `[unowned self]` in one of many closures.

Comment: you can also use [weak self]

Comment: added as an answer @Byoth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your closures, and delegates must be something wrong and your `viewController` is being retained

make sure that your delegates are declared as `weak`,

```
weak var delegate: YourDelegateProtocol
```

and your closure that use `self` are execute either with `[weak self]` or `[unowned self]`

```
let yourClosure : (()->Void) = { [weak self] in
    //your closure implementation
}
```